# Why won't ML.NET Model Builder GPU extension install properly?

Tags: c#, tensorflow, ml.net

When I use ML.NET Model Builder in VS2022 and try to configure the environment, the compatibility check informs me that the GPU extension is missing.

[image]

When I click "Install extension" it leads me to Visual studio's marketplace and suggests I download "ML.NET Model Builder GPU Support 2019" (not 2022).
When I install the ML.NET Model Builder GPU Support 2022 manually the compatibility check still informs me that the GPU extension is missing. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6.4 are both installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU extension was not the issue as VS22 kept stating. Installing the ML.NET Model Builder 2022 [(link)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MLNET.ModelBuilder2022) manually instead of through VS22 solved this problem for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you could answer your own question, accept it. This way you will help others that have the same problem and are looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

The Model Builder and GPU extension versions need to match. Installing the latest version of Model Builder extension and Model Builder GPU extension should resolve this.

Unfortunately in older version of Model Builder the error message doesn't state this.